# How to shorten many if?

Tags: python

Is it possible to shorten my project's code with a dictionary, because once the user executes the program with command line argument of "--template1" or other number in a range 1-4, it assigns the current header, footer to the pre-defined files in their respective paths according to the given command line argument number. I'm wondering is it possible to add those files in a dictionary or to shorten those 100 lines somehow ?

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    all_templates = ('--template1', '--template2', '--template3', '--template4')
    if not sys.argv[1].startswith(all_templates):
        sys.exit("""Usage:  python build.py --template1

""")
    if sys.argv[1].startswith('--'):
        option = sys.argv[1][2:]
        if option == 'template1':
            hf = staticFile("static/template-1/header")
            header = hf()
            header = string.replace(header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            fh = staticFile("static/template-1/header_forum")
            forum_header = fh()
            forum_header = string.replace(forum_header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            sh = staticFile("static/template-1/header_search")
            search_header = sh()
            search_header = string.replace(search_header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            ah = staticFile("static/template-1/header_archive")
            archive_header = ah()
            archive_header = string.replace(archive_header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            fp = staticFile("static/template-1/footer_post")
            footer_p = fp()
            footer_p = string.replace(footer_p, "footer_text", Settings.footer_text)
            fi = staticFile("static/template-1/footer")
            footer_i = fi()
            footer_i = string.replace(footer_i, "footer_text", Settings.footer_text)
        if option == 'template2':
            hf = staticFile("static/template-2/header")
            header = hf()
            header = string.replace(header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            fh = staticFile("static/template-2/header_forum")
            forum_header = fh()
            forum_header = string.replace(forum_header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            sh = staticFile("static/template-2/header_search")
            search_header = sh()
            search_header = string.replace(search_header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            ah = staticFile("static/template-2/header_archive")
            archive_header = ah()
            archive_header = string.replace(archive_header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            fp = staticFile("static/template-2/footer_post")
            footer_p = fp()
            footer_p = string.replace(footer_p, "footer_text", Settings.footer_text)
            fi = staticFile("static/template-2/footer")
            footer_i = fi()
            footer_i = string.replace(footer_i, "footer_text", Settings.footer_text)
        if option == 'template3':
            hf = staticFile("static/template-3/header")
            header = hf()
            header = string.replace(header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            fh = staticFile("static/template-3/header_forum")
            forum_header = fh()
            forum_header = string.replace(forum_header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            sh = staticFile("static/template-3/header_search")
            search_header = sh()
            search_header = string.replace(search_header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            ah = staticFile("static/template-3/header_archive")
            archive_header = ah()
            archive_header = string.replace(archive_header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            fp = staticFile("static/template-3/footer_post")
            footer_p = fp()
            footer_p = string.replace(footer_p, "footer_text", Settings.footer_text)
            fi = staticFile("static/template-3/footer")
            footer_i = fi()
            footer_i = string.replace(footer_i, "footer_text", Settings.footer_text)
        if option == 'template4':
            hf = staticFile("static/template-4/header")
            header = hf()
            header = string.replace(header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            fh = staticFile("static/template-4/header_forum")
            forum_header = fh()
            forum_header = string.replace(forum_header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            sh = staticFile("static/template-4/header_search")
            search_header = sh()
            search_header = string.replace(search_header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            ah = staticFile("static/template-4/header_archive")
            archive_header = ah()
            archive_header = string.replace(archive_header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
            fp = staticFile("static/template-4/footer_post")
            footer_p = fp()
            footer_p = string.replace(footer_p, "footer_text", Settings.footer_text)
            fi = staticFile("static/template-4/footer")
            footer_i = fi()
            footer_i = string.replace(footer_i, "footer_text", Settings.footer_text)
elif len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit("""Usage:  python build.py --template1

""")
elif len(sys.argv) > 2:
    sys.exit("""Usage:  python build.py --template1

""")
else:
    sys.exit("""Usage:  python build.py --template1

""")
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of string interpolation? As far as we see all assigned values only differ and depend on the name of the "option"...so turning this into a smarter solution is straight forward

Comment: what has argparse to do with this issue? Nothing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if option.startswith('template'):
    hf = staticFile("static/{}/header".format(option))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the option **var** value in place of `template-n`:

```
hf = staticFile("static/" + option + "/header")
header = hf()
header = string.replace(header, "site_description", Settings.site_description)
fh = staticFile("static/" + option + "/header_forum")
...
```